# Tacit programming style using F#

Tags: f#, tacit-programming

It's not a practically important issue, but I'd like to see an example of [tacit programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) in F# where my *point-free* functions can have multiple arguments (not in form of a list or tuple).

And secondly, how such functions can manipulate a *complex data structure*. I'm trying it out in F# Interactive, but have no success yet.

I tried, for instance:

```
> (fun _ -> (fun _ -> (+))) 333 222 111 555
```

Is that right way?

And:

```
> (fun _ -> (fun _ -> (+))) "a" "b" "c" "d";;  

val it : string = "cd"
```

Comment: You should use "point-free" rather than "pointless". It's the standard term. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# doesn't contain some of the basic functions that are available in Haskell (mainly because F# programmers usually prefer the explicit style of programming and use pointfree style only in the most obvious cases, where it doesn't hurt readability).

However you can define a few basic combinators like this:

```
// turns curried function into non-curried function and back
let curry f (a, b) = f a b
let uncurry f a b = f (a, b)

// applies the function to the first/second element of a tuple
let first f (a, b) = (f a, b)
let second f (a, b) = (a, f b)
```

Now you can implement the function to add lengths of two strings using combinators as follows:

```
let addLengths = 
  uncurry (( (first String.length) >> (second String.length) ) >> (curry (+)))
```

This constructs two functions that apply `String.length` to first/second element of a tuple, then composes them and then adds the elements of the tuple using `+`. The whole thing is wrapped in `uncurry`, so you get a function of type `string -> string -> int`.

Comment: I've checked that in FSI and it does work! Thank you very much; btw, could you explain how did you get to that tuple-function composition syntax? I mean `(first String.length) >> (second String.length)` It looks somewhat unusual to me ;)

Comment: That's achieved using function composition `>>`. For example `f >> g` means that for an argument `x`, it will call `g(f(x))`. In the case above, the first function (`first String.length`) turns a tuple `string * string` into a tuple `int * string` and the second function (`second String.length`) turns this into `int * int` containing the lengths.

Comment: You're practically implementing arrows for F# ;) Okay, why not - Arrows have been invented as a combination of monads and tacit programming.

Answer (score 2):

In F#, the arity of functions is fixed, so you're not going to be able to write both

```
(op) 1 2
```

and

```
(op) 1 2 3 4
```

for any given operator `op`.  You will need to use a list or other data structure if that's what you want.  If you're just trying to avoid named variables, you can always do "1 + 2 + 3 + 4".  The most idiomatic way to add a list of numbers in F# is `List.sum [1;2;3;4]`, which also avoids variables.